# undefined reference to `gzopen` error

Tags: c, compilation, hyperlink, zlib, undefined-reference

My C program uses some zlib functions (like `gzopen`, `gzread`). I have included the `zlib.h` header file in my program and added the `-lz` option when compiling, but I still get an error that the gz functions have undefined references. I'm using kubuntu 11.10 and got the following packages installed: libgh-zlib-dev, zlib1g-dbg, zlib1g and zlib1g-dev.

i have tried changing the position of the linking command, but no luck. Here is the one i have at the moment:

> CFLAGS=-Wall -pthread -lm -lz -std=c99 -Wextra

Comment: Please show your linking command. You might have put `-lz` in the wrong place.

Comment: how are you exactly compiling? CFLAGS are used by scripts generated with automake, not gcc directly...

Comment: @HubertKario -- CFLAGS is understood (and used) by `make`; it's fed to the C compiler as appropriate.

Comment: like this: gcc -Wall -pthread -lm -lz -std=c99 -Wextra src/main.c -o ad

Comment: Solved it! I tried all positions of -lz inside my CFLAGS, but I actually had to put it AFTER the source file name.. so the command:"gcc -Wall -pthread -lm -std=c99 -Wextra src/main.c -lz -o ad" worked!

Comment: How about answering the question your self with the comment above? Then mark as accepted.

Answer (score 13):

put them as part of LDFLAGS, it should look like:

```
gcc -Wall -pthread  src/main.c -lm -lz -std=c99 -Wextra -o main
```

Comment: /usr/bin/c++  libbpf.c:(.text+0x3115): undefined reference to `gzopen'